# Aligning marginal notes with center of line rather than baseline

Tags: vertical-alignment, margins, labels

I would like to have all references in my document (to equations, figures, lemmas, random locations in text, etc.) be numbered in the same series, and I would like these numbers to appear in the margin.  See [here](http://canyon23.net/math/tc.pdf) for examples: p. 30 (equation and paragraph labels), p. 31 (theorem label and figure label), p. 26 (\item label).

I've managed to cobble together macros which do most of what I want, but two problems remain:

- The marginal label aligns according to the *baseline*, but for displayed equations I would like it to be more centered (see p. 4 of above document).
- I can't get labels for figures into the margin.

Is there a package which does something like this?

Is there a way for TeX to know the height of the current displayed equation, so that I can adjust the vertical position of the marginal note accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a package which does something like this?

I don't know if it does exactly what you ask for, but there's the [showlabels](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=showlabels) package which I've used to do similar things.  It's got some configuration options so may be able to do what you need.